# Google Maps Changing Center

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, events

I'm trying to create an app in AngularJS that has multiple locations and you click on one and it takes you to the location in Google Maps. I'm having an issue with relocating the Map when a location is clicked. I think I need to add an event listener but i'm not sure. The code creating the map is located in `initialize()`. Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.ASiteLocs = [Locations Contained Here...];
  $scope.SSiteLocs = [Locations Contained Here...];
  $scope.SiteLocs = $scope.SSiteLocs.concat($scope.ASiteLocs);

  angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {
    var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
    if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
      location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
      Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0];
      Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1];
      Com = ",";
      location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com, Lat);
    }

    angular.forEach($scope.SSiteLocs, function(object) {
      object.carrier = 'Sprint';
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.ASiteLocs, function(object) {
      object.carrier = 'AT&T';
    });
  });

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.894465, -88.460500),
      zoom: 12
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: site.Point.coordinates,
    map: map,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      map.panTo(site.Point.coordinates);
    }, 1000);
  });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      map.setZoom(8);
      map.setCenter(site.Point.coordinates);
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



  $scope.headerShow = false;
  $scope.tableAttrs = {
    hide: false
  };
});
```

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      height: 100%
    }
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0
    }
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="google-maps@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="map.js"></script>
  <script src="ShowHide.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC0wdLb9-Os4YVxn_JR2sY08xEN-1aJkMM"></script>
  <title>Site ID</title>
</head>

<body link="white" vlink="white">
  <pin>Site ID</pin>
  <center>
    <div id="header" ng-hide="tableAttrs.hide">Site Finder</div>

    <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

      <input type="text" ng-model="search" border="3" placeholder="Please enter site name..." ng-hide="tableAttrs.hide">
      <div link="white" vlink = "white">
      <button id="btn2" ng-click="tableAttrs.hide = !tableAttrs.hide" ng-hide="!tableAttrs.hide" class="button-Overlay">Back To Search</button></div>
      <table border="1" width="100%" ng-hide="tableAttrs.hide" class="buttonOverlay">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td><center>Name</center></td>
            <td>Carrier</td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="site in SiteLocs | filter : search">
            <td>
           <button id="btn1" ng-click="tableAttrs.hide = !tableAttrs.hide">
              {{site.name}}
             </button>
            </td>

            <td>
              {{site.carrier}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


  </center>
  <div id="map-canvas" ng-show="!hideAttr"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this on click on one of the locations:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lon ) );
```

You'll probably need a way to pass the location's lat/lon to the script.